# Pandas Efficient Way to Calculate Annual Inventory Based on Equipment Date Ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to translate a dataframe of equipment date ranges and characteristics into their annual total install time by characteristic groupings.  I'm looking to translate a dataframe like this:

```
df_eq=pd.DataFrame({'equip':np.arange(0,10),'char1':[4]*4+[1,2,3]+[5]*3,
                    'char2':['A']*3+['B']*3+['C']*4,
                    'start':pd.to_datetime(['2010-01-10', '2010-01-10','2011-02-24','2011-06-06','2013-09-30','2010-01-10', '2010-01-10','2011-02-24','2011-06-06','2013-09-30']),
                    'end':pd.to_datetime(['2014-05-05']*2+['2015-01-01']*3+[None]*5)})

df_eq
   char1 char2        end  equip      start
0      4     A 2014-05-05      0 2010-01-10
1      4     A 2014-05-05      1 2010-01-10
2      4     A 2015-01-01      2 2011-02-24
3      4     B 2015-01-01      3 2011-06-06
4      1     B 2015-01-01      4 2013-09-30
5      2     B        NaT      5 2010-01-10
6      3     C        NaT      6 2010-01-10
7      5     C        NaT      7 2011-02-24
8      5     C        NaT      8 2011-06-06
9      5     C        NaT      9 2013-09-30
```

Where the `NaT` datetime's for `end` represent equipment that has not yet been retired.  Using this dataframe I'm looking to translate to produce the following samples where the quantities are the install time of units within the given year:

```
   char1      2011  2012      2013      2014
0      1  0.000000     0  0.254795  1.000000
1      2  1.000000     1  1.000000  1.000000
2      3  1.000000     1  1.000000  1.000000
3      4  3.424658     4  4.000000  2.684932
4      5  1.424658     2  2.254795  3.000000

   char1 char2      2011  2012      2013      2014
0      1     B  0.000000     0  0.254795  1.000000
1      2     B  1.000000     1  1.000000  1.000000
2      3     C  1.000000     1  1.000000  1.000000
3      4     A  2.852055     3  3.000000  1.684932
4      4     B  0.572603     1  1.000000  1.000000
5      5     C  1.424658     2  2.254795  3.000000
```

I can produce the desired tables with the following code, but I'm looking to see if there is a more pythonic way using pandas to produce the same output tables:

```
df_eq.end=df_eq.end.fillna(pd.to_datetime(datetime.date.today()))

def days_in_year(start,end,year):
    start_of_year=pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(year,1,1))
    end_of_year=pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(year,12,31))
    if start.year>year or end.year<year:
        return 0
    initial_date=start_of_year if start_of_year>start else start
    ending_date=end_of_year if end_of_year<end else end
    return (ending_date-initial_date+pd.Timedelta(days=1))/(end_of_year-start_of_year+pd.Timedelta(days=1))

df_inv_yr=pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(map(lambda year: map(lambda srt, end: days_in_year(srt,end,year), df_eq.start,df_eq.end),[2011,2012,2013,2014])).T.tolist(),columns=[2011,2012,2013,2014])

first_sample_output=pd.concat([df_eq,df_inv_yr],axis=1).groupby(['char1'])[[2011,2012,2013,2014]].sum().reset_index()

second_sample_output=pd.concat([df_eq,df_inv_yr],axis=1).groupby(['char1','char2'])[[2011,2012,2013,2014]].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can vectorize some of your code using `.where` like this:

```
def days_in_year(years, df_eq):
    df=df_eq.copy()
    for year in years:
        beg=pd.datetime(year,1,1)
        end=pd.datetime(year+1,1,1)
        df[year]=(df.end.where(df.end<=end,other=end)\
-df.start.where(df.start<=end,other=end).where(df.start>beg, beg))/(end-beg)
    return df

years=range(2011,2015)
df = days_in_year(years,df_eq)
first_sample_output=df.groupby(['char1'])[years].sum().reset_index()
second_sample_output=df.groupby(['char1','char2'])[years].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is much cleaner and improved over what I originally had.